# What is the figure of speech for a word with a hidden meaning

Tags: word-choice

I took a phrase "Change is inevitable"  and got it engraved on a money or coin box..as a gift to a friend who is relocating.I was impressed at myself coming up with it..Change as in difference and change  in terms of money ( keep the change).I am clueless what's the figure of speech of this word change.I would love to find more of it.

Thanks,
Geetha

Comment: It sounds like a "pun".http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is commonly known as a [***pun***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun).

> the usually humorous use of a word in such a way as to suggest two or more of its meanings or the meaning of another word similar in sound
>
> *Merriam-Webster*

Lists of puns are easy to find online, but [here](http://www.punoftheday.com/cgi-bin/disppuns.pl?ord=F)'s a good one to start with.

Answer (score 4):

While "pun" is probably best, an alternative is **double entendre** (pronounced per the original French).

> 1:ambiguity of meaning arising from language that lends itself to more
>   than one interpretation
>
> 2:a word or expression capable of two interpretations with one usually
>   risqué

But, since meaning 2 is by far the most common, a bit of care is needed in applying the term.

Answer (score 1):

[Connotation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/connotation) would be a good one as it describes a word with two meaning.

Comment: Just a small suggestion; include the definition in the answer as block quote. That way if the link ever goes dead, the information is still here.